# How to list all symbols em++ has found?

Tags: javascript, c++, linker, llvm, emscripten

I'm using `emcc`/`em++`, tried to link several LLVM byte codes, but some of them fail.

```
$ em++ -std=c++11 \
 -o _assimp.js \
 -O2 \
 --memory-init-file 0 \
 -I../include \
 code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/*.o \
 code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/__/contrib/ConvertUTF/*.o \
 code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/__/contrib/unzip/unzip.c.o \
 ../port/emscripten/emassimp.cpp
```

The problem is that it says there are several symbols not found.

```
warning: unresolved symbol: inflateEnd
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN6Assimp3FBX6ObjectC2EyRKNS0_7ElementERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE
warning: unresolved symbol: inflateInit_
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN6Assimp3FBX6ObjectD2Ev
warning: unresolved symbol: inflate
```

It seems that symbol `inflate` was not resolved, but it surely exists in unzip.c.o.

```
$ file unzip.c.o
unzip.c.o: LLVM IR bitcode
$ llvm-nm unzip.c.o
         U crc32
-------- t decrypt_byte
         U fill_fopen_filefunc
         U free
         U get_crc_table
         U inflate
         U inflateEnd
         U inflateInit2_
-------- t init_keys
         U malloc
         U strcmp
-------- t strcmpcasenosensitive_internal
         U strlen
-------- T unzClose
-------- T unzCloseCurrentFile
-------- T unzGetCurrentFileInfo
-------- T unzGetFilePos
-------- T unzGetGlobalComment
-------- T unzGetGlobalInfo
-------- T unzGetLocalExtrafield
-------- T unzGetOffset
-------- T unzGoToFilePos
-------- T unzGoToFirstFile
-------- T unzGoToNextFile
-------- T unzLocateFile
-------- T unzOpen
-------- T unzOpen2
-------- T unzOpenCurrentFile
-------- T unzOpenCurrentFile2
-------- T unzOpenCurrentFile3
-------- T unzOpenCurrentFilePassword
-------- T unzReadCurrentFile
-------- T unzSetOffset
-------- T unzStringFileNameCompare
-------- D unz_copyright
-------- T unzeof
-------- t unzlocal_CheckCurrentFileCoherencyHeader
-------- t unzlocal_DosDateToTmuDate
-------- t unzlocal_GetCurrentFileInfoInternal
-------- t unzlocal_SearchCentralDir
-------- t unzlocal_getByte
-------- t unzlocal_getLong
-------- t unzlocal_getShort
-------- T unztell
-------- t update_keys
```

Actually, are there any ways to see what `em++` has resolved as a symbol? It will be better if I can understand the reason why symbols in unzip.c.o was ignored by `em++`.

Comment: `U inflate` means the symbol is referenced but undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of llvm-nm clearly shows that this file does not have the symbol.

Try to do a llvm-nm on all object files created by your project to be sure you have definition of these missing symbols. Using grep can help.